# Send Tokens To Address, or Public Key?

Tags: tokens, addresses, public-key

I had a look at this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhdDQXLCRpE

I can send tokens to MyEtherWallet from my exchange. Do I have to withdraw to my public key? Or, can I send it to one of my Ethereum addresses?

Comment: the public key of your ethereum accounts should be the same as your address, maybe you would like to clarify what do you mean by addresses and public key because they are the same

Comment: Ah. I see what you are saying. The first address at m/44'/60'/0'/0 on Ethereum addresses is the same as the public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The address is the last 20 bytes of the hash of the public key.

Check this post here for more details.
[Ethereum Address vs Public Key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/ethereum-address-vs-public-key)

When you're sending something, you're always sending to the address and not to the public key.